# Error Message when creating a feature table in databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, feature-store

I am currently trying to create a feature table and write the data from a dataframe into it:

```
from databricks import feature_store
from databricks.feature_store import feature_table
from databricks.feature_store import FeatureStoreClient

pyspark_df = dataframe.to_spark()

fs = FeatureStoreClient()

customer_feature_table = fs.create_table(
  name='FeatureStore.Features',
  primary_keys=['ID1', 'ID2'],
  schema = pyspark_df.schema,
  description='CustomerProfit features'
)

fs.write_table(
  name='FeatureStore.Features',
  df = pyspark_df,
  mode = 'overwrite'
)
```

If I execute this code I run into the following error mesage:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 554.0 failed 4
times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 554.0 (TID 1100) (10.139.64.9 executor 19):
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 19 exited caused by one of the running tasks) 
Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. 
Check driver logs for WARN messages.
```

I am using a the runtime version:  10.3 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)

I tried the same code on a smaller dataframe and it worked. I also tried to use a more powerful "driver type" but I still run into the issue. Why do I run into that error and is there some solution or workaround?

Comment: what kind of transformation are you doing? Are you using any Python user-defined functions?

Comment: @AlexOtt Before I get to the point where i want to save the data I am doing some basic Data preparation, which also includes a user defined function.

Comment: Try to avoid use of UDFs. Also, maybe try bigger nodes types for workers (not for driver)

Comment: @AlexOtt Alright I got rid of the UDF and choose a bigger node. Unfortunately it is still not working. The dataframe I try to safe has quite some columns (~180) and millions of rows. Maybe it is just too big for the feature store...

Answer (score 1):

Try using partition_columns. It will facilitate the writing and loading of the data.
visit https://docs.databricks.com/machine-learning/feature-store/feature-tables.html for more information.

```
  fs.create_table(
  name=table_name,
  primary_keys = ['ID1', 'ID2'],
  df = df,
  partition_columns = "ID1",
  description = "enter table description"

)
```

Comment: upvoted: it is nearly always a good idea to have partition_columns in the mix.  One thing I wonder is how that works with the underlying `delta` tables